# Manifest error lanching spring-boot as java application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, manifest.mf

I can't run my Spring Boot application in my eclipse 3.9.0RELEASE. 
It runs fine if launched on Prompt with the command:

> mvn spring-boot:run

But I prefer using my Spring Client instead of the Command Prompt, 
and when I try to run it, doing: Run As-> Java Application or Spring Boor App , then i get this error:

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar file:/C:/Users/MyFirstName%20MySecondName/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.7/groovy-2.4.7.jar
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:100)
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.fromUrlClassLoader(ChangeableUrls.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.(Restarter.java:134)
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:531)
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartedEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:64)
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:46)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:60)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.started(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
>       at com.myshop.demo.Application.main(Application.java:26)

It seems to me that the IDE cannot succesfully create the **manifest.mf** file (while instead the maven plugin do it perfectly) but i have no clue how to resolve this.

I've also tried to create myself the file  pasting in my project pah: src/main/resources/META-INF/manifest.mf the one found in the jar, created with maven plugin.

**manifest.mf:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: demo
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: MyFirstName MySecondName
Start-Class: com.myshop.demo.Application
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.myshop
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.3.6.RELEASE
Created-By: Apache Maven
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
Implementation-Vendor: Pivotal Software, Inc.
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

But the error didn't changed.
Thank you for any help.

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.myshop</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- hot swapping, disable cache for template, enable live reload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion> 
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.myshop.demo</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>     
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Application.java:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
  public class Application {    
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: up....................

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a devtools startup exception, remove that dependecy from pom.xml then rerun the application.

Answer (score 0):

The `groovy-2.4.7.jar` file was corrupted.

Try to manually download the file from the internet and copy it to `C:/Users/MyFirstName%20MySecondName/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.7/groovy-2.4.7.jar`

It should work.